# How to fix error in R regarding spakly model

Tags: r, sparklyr

Can some help me with error im getting in R sparkly

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>%
   select(Petal_Width, Petal_Length) %>%
   ml_kmeans(centers = 3)
```

> Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "features" does not
>   exist. Available fields: Petal_Width, Petal_Length
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:274)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(StructType.scala:274)
>
>     at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
>
>     at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.apply(StructType.scala:273)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.checkColumnTypes(SchemaUtils.scala:58)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.util.SchemaUtils$.validateVectorCompatibleColumn(SchemaUtils.scala:119)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansParams$class.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:96)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.validateAndTransformSchema(KMeans.scala:285)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.transformSchema(KMeans.scala:382)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(KMeans.scala:341)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans$$anonfun$fit$1.apply(KMeans.scala:340)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$$anonfun$11.apply(Instrumentation.scala:183)
>
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:183)
>
>     at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:340)
>
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:139)
>
>     at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
>
>     at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
>
>     at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
>
>     at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>
>     at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>
>     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
>
>     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>
>     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
>
>     at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
>
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```
>
> Warning: Some components of ... were not used: centers

I already tried to use other function, but it doesn't wotk for 3 clusters and picking up only 2

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>% 
ml_kmeans(formula= ~ Petal_Width + Petal_Length, centers = 3)

#Warning: Some components of ... were not used: centers

print(kmeans_model)
#K-means clustering with 2 clusters
#
#Cluster centers:
#  Petal_Width Petal_Length
#1   1.6818182     4.925253
#2   0.2627451     1.492157
#
#Within Set Sum of Squared Errors =  86.39022>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of your error is very straight forward:

> Field "features" does not exist.

If you check the documentation for `?ml_kmeans` you would see that you need to either specify a formula (your second attempt) or the features_col. Now a qucik note, in Spark features for a model are expected to be vectorized within one column of a `data.frame`

Your second error/warning message is also straight forward:

> Warning: Some components of ... were not used: centers

`centers` is not a parameter in `ml_kmeans`. What you want to use is `k`

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>% 
       ml_kmeans(formula= ~ Petal_Width + Petal_Length, k = 3)

kmeans_model
# K-means clustering with 3 clusters
# 
# Cluster centers:
#   Petal_Width Petal_Length
# 1    1.359259     4.292593
# 2    0.246000     1.462000
# 3    2.047826     5.626087
# 
# Within Set Sum of Squared Errors =  31.41289
```

To run without a formula you need to use `ft_vector_assembler`

```
kmeans_model <- iris_tbl %>% 
  ft_vector_assembler(input_cols=c("Sepal_Width","Petal_Length"), output_col="features") %>%
  ml_kmeans(k = 3)
```

Comment: and how do i do it with features? (first option) sorry for silly question, im really trying to figure it out. Thank you so much for pointing out regarding k!!!

Comment: because im trying to make ggplot after for the clustering data and having this erro if im using ml formula: sdf_predict(kmeans_model) %>%
+   collect() %>%
+   ggplot(aes(Petal_Length, Petal_Width)) +
+   geom_point(aes(Petal_Width, Petal_Length, col = factor(prediction+1)),
+              size = 2, alpha = 0.5) + 
+   geom_point(data = kmeans_model$centers, aes(Petal_Width, Petal_Length),
+              pch = 'x', size = 12) +
+   scale_color_discrete(name = "Predicted cluster")

Comment: Error in ml_predict(model, sdf_register(x), ...) : 
  argument "model" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
'sdf_predict' is deprecated.
Use 'ml_predict' instead.
See help("Deprecated")

Comment: ml_predict(kmeans_model) %>%
+ collect() %>%
+   ggplot(aes(Petal_Length, Petal_Width)) +
+   geom_point(aes(Petal_Width, Petal_Length, col = factor(prediction+1)),
+              size = 2, alpha = 0.5) + 
+   geom_point(data = kmeans_model$k, aes(Petal_Width, Petal_Length),
+              pch = 'x', size = 12) +
+   scale_color_discrete(name = "Predicted cluster")


error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Petal_Width' not found
BUT petal width is definitely there

Comment: It's in the documentation for the function you are trying to call: `sdf_predict` requires a model and **data** same goes for `ml_predict` you are only passing in the model

Comment: you need to add the dataset to the ml_predict call: `ml_predict(x=kmeans_model, dataset=iris_tbl) %>% ...`

Comment: thank you for your time and patience! it was really helpful!